# Size of an array inherited virtually from two classes

Tags: c++, virtual, sizeof, base-class

Consider the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
class base {
  int arr[10];     
};
  
class b1: virtual public base { };
  
class b2: virtual public base { };
  
class derived: public b1, public b2 {};
  
int main(void)
{ 
  cout<<sizeof(derived);
   return 0;
}
```

According to me, the array arr is inherited only once in the class due to virtual base class. Hence sizeof derived class should be 10*4=40 bytes. However, on execution, this program is printing 56 as the output. I even checked the size of int on the compiler, it was 4 bytes only. Can someone explain me where are the additional 16 bytes coming from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of the classes in case of virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541149/size-of-the-classes-in-case-of-virtual-inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably size of v-table for keeping virtual function addresses. If you check `b1` or `b2`, it is 48 bytes, probably a pointer to v-table(pointer on 64 bit system is 8 bytes). same thing happens for next inheritance increasing size by 8 more.

**Side note:** I think it is v-table because if you compile your code as a 32-bit program, the increase of sizes will be 4 bytes(pointer in 32 bit system). In addition, if you remove `virtual` keyword the size will not increase anymore, so it is obviously something related to `virtual` calls and first thing that comes to mind is v-table.

Comment: Is there any way we can confirm whether it is actually size of v-table or not?

Comment: @loveofprogramming updated answer. if you remove `virtual` keyword, your size will not increase anymore(in case of `b1` and `b2`) and compiling 32 bit increase only by 4. So I'm almost sure that it is size of a pointer related to `virtual` calls and first thing that is necessary is v-table.

Comment: How did you compile it using 32 bit, by the way?

Comment: @loveofprogramming if you use clang or gcc, add `-m32`.

Comment: There are no virtual functions, so there is no virtual function table (vtable).

Comment: Then @JaMiT can you explain the answer to this question

Comment: @loveofprogramming See the duplicate I proposed. The pointers are to the virtual base class (within the object), not to virtual function tables.