# virtual pointer size varies based on class data members

Tags: c++, virtual

As explained in one of the solutions of this question ([Size of virtual pointer-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604176/size-of-virtual-pointer-c)) that you can calculate virtual pointer size in following manner :

```
struct virtual_base {
    int data;
    virtual_base() {}
    virtual ~virtual_base() {}
};

struct non_virtual_base {
    int data;
    non_virtual_base() {}
    ~non_virtual_base() {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof( virtual_base ) - sizeof( non_virtual_base ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

But when i try this on cpp.sh http://cpp.sh/7o5av, without data (member variable) i get the size as 7 and with data size is coming out to be 12, so i failed to understand this behavior and any insights will be helpful and i know that size of empty class is 1 and in second with data member i expect this should come as 11 and not 7

Comment: ok then what could the reliable manner in which vptr size can be calculated programatically

Comment: The issue is that the non-virtual class without data has size 1, even though it doesn't actually have anything in it, because size can never be 0. So `sizeof(non_virtual_base)` doesn't really show how much space is being used by the struct.

Comment: Also beware of alignment issues: if the vTable is not exactly N*64 bit long the compiler might add some padding space in between members.

Comment: But an empty virtual class doesn't need to add 1 to the size, because the VPTR uses space (it's like an extra data member). This is why you need to use classes with at least 1 data member for this to work correctly.

Comment: @PhilipV The vtable isn't in each object, it's a per-class data structure. The object just contains a pointer to it.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that class with no data member have size = 1 that's why i assume that without data member size will come as 11 (12 for vptr and 1 for empty class)

Comment: The size of a "virtual pointer" is the size of a pointer. It's simple to calculate, since all data pointers are the same size (this isn't a literal requirement, but in practice it's always true). So the size of the "virtual pointer" is `sizeof(void*)`. The code in the question calculates the difference in size between two classes that differ in the presence or absence of a virtual function. As the answers are suggesting, that difference is implementation-specific, and may well involve more than the presence or absence of a vtable pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You get `7` with no data member becuase the empty class has size `1` so while the virtual one contains a pointer to the virtual table of size 8: `8-1=7`.

When data members are involved the result you get depends on the actual type of the members. If you use `int` then the difference is `12` becuase the vptr has to be aligned to multiple of `8`.
This means that the int data member occupies bytes frm 0 to 4 and the vptr cannot be stored at byte `4` but starting from at byte 8. So the total size is `8+8=16` for the virtual struct. Try using a double and you will see that the difference is `8` as in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct virtual_base {
    double data;
    virtual_base() {}
    virtual ~virtual_base() {}
};

struct non_virtual_base {
    double data;
    non_virtual_base() {}
    ~non_virtual_base() {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof( virtual_base ) - sizeof( non_virtual_base ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

try here: https://www.ideone.com/Ycpg64

Comment: So is there any reliable way to get size of vptr programatically

Comment: Then why this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604176/size-of-virtual-pointer-c if it's simply equal to pointer size

Comment: Can i safely assume sizeof(void*) is same as size of vptr

Comment: @Kapil What they're actually asking is how much extra space is used in the object when it has a virtual pointer. Because of alignment, the overhead may be more than just the size of the pointer. Why do you care about the pointer size itself?

Answer (score 1):

`virtual_base` only contains the `vftable` pointer which is apparently 8 bytes on your platform. `virtual_base` also has an int, and the `vftable` is aligned to 8 bytes. So it's something like:

```
4 bytes for int |  4 padding bytes  |  8 bytes for vftable pointer  | 
| x | x | x | x |    |    |    |    | v | v | v | v | v | v | v | v |
```

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439240/sizeof-class-with-int-function-virtual-function-in-c). It might be helpful.

**With `int` data member:**

- `sizeof(virtual_base) is` 16 [4(int)+ 4(padding) +8(vftable)] bytes
- `sizeof(non_virtual_base)` is 4 bytes i.e. size of `int`.

**Without `int` data member:**

- `sizeof(virtual_base) is` 8 bytes i.e the size of vftable pointer. There is no padding.
- `sizeof(non_virtual_base)` without any data member is 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare any function as `virtual` in C++, the class receives a hidden member `vptr`, which points to `vtable`. This is used to choose which function should actually be called when [dynamic polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) is used.

*Disclaimer:* I'll be using results from online compiler you posted, with the options you set (C++14, O2 optimization)

We can easily see that empty class has `sizeof` equal to 1, and `sizeof` class with virtual functions is 8.
Then, with data member, class without virtual functions gets `sizeof` 4 and the one with virtual functions get `sizeof` 16.
We can also check that `sizeof` pointer type (for example int*) is equal to 8

So, what happens here: empty class gets assigned size 1 by default. But, a class with virtual functions must have `vptr` member, which itself is 8 bytes long. This gives you 8-1 = 7

When you add member to non-virtual class, it simply gets the size of all it's members, in this case it's int, so you have size 4.
For virtual class, you already have `vptr` of size 8 and add int of size 4 to it. Here the mechanism of [structure alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360612/structure-alignment-padding-largest-size-of-padding-and-order-of-struct-member) kicks in. Presumably, the system it's compiling allows for access only to bytes which are on offset of multiply of 8, so the compiler, to optimize access time, adds artifial *padding* bytes, which hold no data. Basically, object of your class would look like this:
`[int(4B)|padding(4B)|vptr(8B)]`
This results in size of class being 16. So we get 16 - 4 = 12.